# What's the difference between ftp@user and ftp://domain

Tags: url, ftp

What's the difference between these two URLs?

```
ftp://user@101.101.101.49/folder/request.js
```

```
ftp://test.net@ftp.website.net/folder/request.js
```

(Note that the IP is only for sample.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is particularly different.  The part before the `@` is your username.  The part after the `@` is the remote host you're connecting to.

`101.101.101.49` is by IP address
`ftp.website.net` is by hostname

The `/folder/request.js` is the path and filename you're looking to download.